# Url hash as password

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

When user types url with custom hash ex url: **example.com/YT6pTeHDNoROFuXeeDiS**

then website validates that hash as a password

and then redirects to ex url: **example.com/placeToBe**

but when directly accessed **example.com/placeToBe** it will ask that custom hash or show error page or redirects

in short:
**YT6pTeHDNoROFuXeeDiS** corresponds to **placeToBe** directory and not the other way around


db example:
**MJJFWYQYKLXULGTWIE5M** => **placeToBe1**
**3O5OBD77M5S12ZD2PHXY** => **placeToBe2**
**IHVL7LMRTL02NJJN6LPA** => **placeToBe3**
**...**


I know how to do this in php:
when hash url entered then browser is redirected to custom 404 page,
then that 404 page contains filter for hash, if hash passes and validates
then script creates cookie for corresponding dir and then
redirects to that directory
directory index kindly checks, ok you got my cookie :D and then allows to browse
its content.

But my interest lies in .htaccess and apache sorcery, thus my question:
**how can I conditionally set and check a cookie with and then redirect to right dir using .htaccess?**

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do a bit better than that to enforce access-restriction using htaccess:

1. Set a cookie with a random value when they log in
2. Create a file that corresponds to that value in some location
3. Send users directly to the access restricted url

Then, add conditional rewrite rules:

- If the file whose name corresponds to the cookie exists let them through
- If not, redirect the user to a 403 or a login screen

My RewriteRule-foo is a bit rusty, but you basically need to use a capturing regex on `%{HTTP_COOKIE}` in a first RewriteCond, and then use the capture in the follow-up RewriteCond to check if a file exists (using `-f`).

If it all clears out, then:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

In a subsequent rule, only check for the cookie's presence, and return a 403 if it is:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

And in a last rule, return a login screen; for instance:

```
RewriteRule ^ /login [L]
```

Oh, and in each case, it goes without saying that a first RewriteCond should only enforce those rules on restricted URIs — else you'll get 500-errors due to rewrite looping on your login screen, for instance.

When users log out, delete the cookie and the corresponding file.

To remove loose ends, periodically delete expired files, e.g. if the cookie is set for a week, the corresponding files that are older than a week should get trashed, and touch existing files when a user refreshes his session.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need **.htaccess** / **mod_rewrite** to do what you want at all.

Instead of forcing users to go to urls like:

> example.com/YT6pTeHDNoROFuXeeDiS

Give them such url:

> example.com/validation.php?hash=YT6pTeHDNoROFuXeeDiS

and in **validation.php**:

```
if (isset($_GET['hash']))
{
   // do your validation stuff here

   // redirect to some place - if you want but there is no need - you can
   // do everything here
   header( 'HTTP/1.1 303 See Other' );
   header( "Location: someUrl" );    
}
else
{
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 303 See Other' );
    header( "Location: someOtherUrl" );    
}
```